# end_request i/o error, dev sdc sector xxxx - SSD crash?

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive, ssd, smart

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and it seems like my SSD is failing on me.
After an arbitrary amount of time the disk just prints `end_request i/o error, dev sdc sector xxx` when I enter a command like `ls` or anything else.
It can happen after 24hours or just a few minutes.

All the SMART tests (short/extended) pass and there are no reallocated sectors, although I'm not sure if SSDs handle it like the older magnetic types.

Program fail count seems to be the glaring problem in the SMART log. 
4745980543444 fails? Is that almost 5 trillion?

Is there anything I can do especially different than a normal hard disk drive?

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     M4-CT064M4SSD2
Serial Number:    0000000011290314D92E
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 10314d92e
Firmware Version: 0009
User Capacity:    64,023,257,088 bytes [64.0 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ATA-8-ACS revision 6
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 13 17:55:36 2013 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  295) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   4) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       5385
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       563
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
171 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       22
174 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       4745980543444
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x000e   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       60
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Data_Address_Mark_Errs  0x0018   100   100   001    Old_age   Offline      -       0
206 Flying_Height           0x000e   100   100   001    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5385         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5385         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      5381         -
# 4  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      3907         -
# 5  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      3884         -
# 6  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%      3880         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is more likely to be a cruddy firmware than anything too serious. See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087161/can-crucial-micron-ssd-call-home-for-news

Here's the relevant gumph:

> This drive may hang after 5184 hours of power-on time:
>    http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Crucial-m4-Firmware-BSOD,14544.html
>    See the following web pages for firmware updates:
>    http://www.crucial.com/support/firmware.aspx
>    http://www.micron.com/products/solid-state-storage/client-ssd#software

You've crossed 5184 (recently) so that looks all the more relevant.

Either way, back up and be prepared it bail out onto another disk.

Comment: Oh wow, that really may be the problem, great find. Although the firmware is only available for Windows and Mac OSX. And will I need to reinstall after updating the firmware?

I'll accept this as an answer after updating.

Comment: Found a booting ISO without the need of Win/Mac here: http://www.crucial.com/firmware/m4/070H/ISO_crucial-c400.070H.07.00.zip

Comment: The instructions say "If performed correctly, there will be no loss of system or user data on the drive."... But if it doesn't go right... Yeah. ***MAKE A BACKUP!*** The third option is a bootable ISO which you should be able to write to USB with one of the various ISO writing applications (image-writer for one).

Comment: Yes, I already made a backup when it first occured. Now I updated via bootable USB _(after burning a printable DVD and realizing my Ubuntu box doesn't have DVD drive)_ and it went fine so far. Thanks!